# Angularjs cant find view, tried everything I know

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

**I have made** a project using ng.Net template from visual studio, i got it up and running, **i added** a new ProgramController.cs, Program.cshtml template, programCtrl.js angular controller, and a program angular module.

**And it just will not work.**

I have a ASP.NET web api and angularjs on clientside.

Here are 2 example routes:

```
    $routeProvider.when('/todomanager', {
    templateUrl: 'App/TodoManager',
        controller: 'todoManagerCtrl'
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/program', {
        templateUrl: 'App/Program',
        controller: 'programCtrl'
    });
```

And what they do backend:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public List<Program> GetPrograms()
    {
        string userId = Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var currentUser = UserManager.FindById(userId);
        return currentUser.Programs;
        //return db.Programs;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public List<todoItem> GetUserTodoItems()
    {
        string userId = Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Identity.GetUserId();

        var currentUser = UserManager.FindById(userId);
        return currentUser.todoItems;
    }
```

The first one works, the second one gives tpload compile error (could not find template view)

I can get the TodoManager view if I call it in /program

But I cant reach my program.cshtml. It's in the same folder as TodoManager.cshtml

I could provide more code, But I dont know which, Because it all works.

My closest guess so far, is that I dont have access to that view, I'm being blocked by a blockviewhandler or the view doesnt exist.

I have the access.
If it was the viewblockhandler it would also block TodoManager.cshtml
And it exists xD I'm looking at it..

It's like i'm spamming 4 + 4 on a calculator and it keeps returning 5..

Please, anything, been stuck for 2 workdays.

**EDIT additional code**

```
//RouteConfig RegisterRoutes
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "App",
            url: "{url}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Main", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Main", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


    }

//WebApiConfig Register
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        //I chaned the routeTemplate so that methods/services would be identified by their action, and not by their parameters.
        //I was getting conflicts if I had more than one GET services, that had identical parameter options, but totally different return data.
        //Adding the action to the routeTemplte correct this issue.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",        //routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }

//blockviewhandler in Web.config
    <handlers>
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*." verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
</handlers>
```

Edit: Project structure, i have a HomeController that returns my Index.cshtml in there, i have my ng-view which is where my views should be rendered.

[image]
Many seem to misunderstand my real question, i want to know:

**How is it, that the todoManager works, and the program does not.**

Comment: What does the network panel in the browser's devtools say when it tries to load the various templates?

Comment: Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$compile/tpload?p0=App%2FProgram

Comment: Only when i try the Program.cshtml. all other views works, i have built this on top of a template.

Comment: No, the network panel. Does it try to fetch the URL, and what does the server respond with?

Comment: Oh sorry, misunderstood, No it just says it couldnt find /App/program, but with the other views it successfully calls the given controller method

Comment: GET http://localhost:33651/App/Program 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Is the casing right? E.g. Program and not program for the filename?

Comment: Casing checked 70 times

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93242/discussion-between-kasper-solvstrom-and-matsemann).

Comment: the first thing I see here is that you posted an Angular (javascript) route configuration and then posted a series of C# code that has nothing to do with those routes.  You seem to have mixed up server side routing and client side routing here, especially given that you are describing your server side .cshtml files as if they were angular .html templates.

Comment: if you jump back into the chat that @KasperSølvstrøm created for you yesterday, we can try and discuss this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using ASP.NET MVC, Web API etc. you should add "every" view to the mvc controller, you probably have something like this in one of your controllers:

```
public ActionResult TodoManager()
{
   return PartialView();
}
```

assuming you are following a tutorial or modifying a sample it is probably in `Controllers/AppController`. If true you must add your another view as:

```
public ActionResult Program()
{
   return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: That is not it, my API returns a List<Program>, just like my other method returning a List<todoItems>

Comment: Not in your api controller as I said, every cshtml served by .Net MVC needs a controller action. There must be another controller in your project structure

Comment: just check your controllers folder

Comment: Edited my post, see in the bottom for project structure.

Comment: just add the my second function to your HomeController if App/Program is a partial template or use View() instead PartialView() and try from browser to get App/Program it should return your template

Comment: As stated in my question, i have no need for alternative solutions, i have a need to understand why my current does not work.

Comment: I don't think you have read my answer. BTW this is not about angular anyway. You must explicitly say to asp.net that you have a template as cshtml and needs to be served. Angular says that it "can't find the template" because your application doesn't serving anything at that url. You should probably learn how asp.net mvc works first

Comment: I will make it very clearly, what my question is, read the edit, the todomanager does not return a view, or a partial view, it returns a list. the only view returned by asp.net is Index.cshtml, angular renders the templates on the client, that is the core of a SPA

Comment: @KasperSølvstrøm You have shown code that returns a List<todoitem> and List<Program> but that is clearly not what Angular needs or wants. You want some HTML, which means you need some action method elsewhere that will return that view. Huseyin is on the right track, please read his answer carefully before declaring that he's off track.

Comment: How come, that the return of the List<todoitem> gets returned to the todoManagerCtrl, and put into the TodoManger.cshtml ? in that case, it's clearly what angular wants. it works perfectly, by returning a List. again i dont think you get it, One of them works, thats my point.

Comment: @KasperSølvstrøm you are definitely confused about the way that Angular Routing, ASP.Net MVC Routing, and ASP.Net WebAPI Routing work, and how they all interact with each other.  There are 3! routing engines at play here, and you have only listed *partial* code for two of them.  As I stated in my comment to the main question, if you pop back into the chat from yesterday, I am willing to help you sort this out.

Comment: I bow in the dust :) thanks Claies for the awsome help, and Huseyin, you were right!